# SQL Server CE 3.5 'select distinct' probleme

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have a problem with a query using SQL Server CE 3.5 and c#

Here is what my table look like:

```
start      | end        | matricul
-----------+------------+---------
29/01/2012 | 29/01/2013 | 22453
29/01/2012 | 29/01/2013 | 22454
29/01/2012 | 29/01/2013 | 22455
29/01/2011 | 29/01/2012 | 22458
29/02/2012 | 29/02/2013 | 22440
```

This is what I'd like to have:

```
start      | end        | matricul
-----------+------------+---------
29/01/2012 | 29/01/2013 | 22453
29/01/2011 | 29/01/2012 | 22458
29/02/2012 | 29/02/2013 | 22440
```

When I execute this query :

```
string query = "SELECT DISTINCT(start) FROM mytable "
```

I get the same result (same as the  first table).

I try using the group by close like this:

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(start),end,matricul FROM mytable GROUP BY start";
```

but it gave me an error.

Please any help would be appreciated

Comment: "an error" - what error?

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure the query shown (select distinct(start) from mytable) does **not** result in a table with 3 columns... Unless that's using some very odd interpretation of SQL rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you group only by "start", you cannot return "end" and "matricul" - as there could be multiple rows for each. You can return *aggrgates* of those (the min or max, for example) - however, I expect you just need:

```
select distinct start, end, matricul
from mytable
```

You can also write this as a group:

```
select start, end, matricul
from mytable
group by start, end, matricul
```

Or maybe:

```
select start, end, sum(matricul)
from mytable
group by start, end
```

Depending on wht "matricul" means :p

Comment: the problem here: 'SELECT distinct start' does nothing, it's like if i write SELECT start  it's return the same result and i don't know why

Answer (score 2):

To achieve a resultset with 3 rows that you mentioned in your question, you'll probably need something like this:

```
select
    start, [end], min(matricul)
from
    tablename
group by
    start, [end]
```

Notice the square brackets: `end` is a reserved word, and can cause troubles on some DBMS-s.

Comment: no this is just an abriviation the real name is end_date. by the way my probleme is solved thanks for everybody :)